# Non Countable set - All points are boundary points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am looking for some examples on R for non countable set that all points are boundary points.

Definition for boundary point (Bartle book): x is a boundary point of A if every neighborhood of x contains points in A and points in Ac

One example that I can intuitively think of are the irrational numbers, but I am not really sure how to formaly prove this.

Thank you

Comment: But Irrational numbers are not countable.... Do you mean RATIONALS instead?

Comment: I am looking for non countable, I edited the question.

Comment: You did not edit the title.

Comment: Cantor set would do the job, I think.

Comment: irrationals would do the job, too. Between any two irrationals a rational, and vice-versa.  So ANY rational ball centered on an irrational contains a rational ... and then, the ball centered on the original irrational to that rational contains an irrational ... smaller ball always included in larger ball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prove a general result:

> If $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, every point of $A$ is a boundary point of $A$ if and only if $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

Once you have that, you just need to find uncountable subsets of $\Bbb R$ whose complements are dense in $\Bbb R$. The irrationals are one such set. As noted in the comments, the middle-thirds Cantor set is another. If $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $a<b$, $(a,b)\setminus\Bbb Q$ is yet another.

Comment: Your answer was extremely helpful, I accepted it

Comment: @Beaba: I’m glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For the Irrationals, take into account that between any to different real numbers always lies a rational and an irrational number.